# Android does not recognize files with .WMV extension?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-4.4-kitkat

Default gallery does not even detect the presence of files with .WMV extension. Can someone give pointers on where the modifications are required in android AOSP? I am using kitkat 4.2.2

As as quick check I enabled the flag to true in /etc/media_codecs.xml

```
VideoDecoderCap name="wmv" enabled="true"
```

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

As we had a similar issue recently, please be sure, that your device actually supports these files. In some circumstances the files are filtered out, as Android can't read the meta data from the video header. Basically, it is missing the appropriate codecs to do so. The supported codecs of android can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core